# Using Twig_SimpleFilter

Tags: symfony, twig-extension

I use a twig function that is deprecated, Twig_Filter_Function. I'm suppose to use Twig_SimpleFilter instead. I'm not 100% sure how to use it though.

This is what I currently have;

```
public function getFilters() 
{
    return array(
        'is_numeric'   => new \Twig_Filter_Function('is_numeric'),
        'number_format'   => new \Twig_Filter_Function('number_format')
    );
}
```

Now the Twig_SimpleFilter require at least two parameters, a $name, and a $callable is the two parameters. Now I'm not 100% sure to replace the Twig_Filter_Function. What should be the two parameters? Is a random name for both fine, and the 'is_numeric' and 'number_format' fine for the second one like this?;

```
public function getFilters() 
{
    return array(
        'is_numeric'   => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('isNumeric', 'is_numeric'),
        'number_format'   => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('numberFormat', 'number_format')
    );
}
```

I've tried it like this, and it seems to be OK. I just want to make 100% sure, or should I do it now on a complete different way? Any help please?

Comment: The second param is a callable, use `array($this, 'method')` where `method` is a public function of the current twig extension class

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on it please? What is 'method'? What should I use? Sorry, I'm not really familiar with Twig extensions.  I just know Symfony now a bit in a few months. I work on a project somebody built, but left before I arrived